# The "randomword" can not access the .length method. Why is that?

Tags: java, string, string-length

I am trying to make a hangman game and I have a problem with finding the length of the random word chosen automatically

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        int upperbound = 40; 
        int int_random = rand.nextInt(upperbound); 
        
        Dictionary S1 = new Dictionary();
        S1.printInfo(); 
        Dictionary randomword = new Dictionary();
        randomword.getWord(int_random); 
        
        char[] letters = new char[(randomword.length)];
        int lives = 8;
        Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while (lives > 0) {
            
            //System.out.println("The random word is now: " +);
            System.out.println("You have" + lives + "guesses left.");
        
            for(int i= 0; i < lives; i++) {
                System.out.println("0") ;
            }
        
            System.out.println("Your guess:");
            String guess = answer.nextLine();
            char letter = guess.charAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class Dictionary {

    public String getWord(int index) {
        switch (index) {
        case 0: return "UNIVERSITY";
        ...
        default: return "Illegal index";
        }
    }
```

I was expecting to be able to use .length in "randomword" but i can not

Comment: You did not show the implementation of `Dictionary`. If I had to guess, I would say that `Dictionary` does not have a (public accessible) field `length`.

Comment: Looks like typo - I'm pretty sure in hangman you use guess letters of random word (`char[] letters = new char[(randomword.getWord(int_random).length)];` ) and not something like "a letter from each supported word" (as current code fails to do by using length of "Dictionary"). Side note: naming is important - "list of words" should never be named `randomword` to avoid such confusion (if `words` not enough at very least make it plural: `randomwords`).

Comment: I fixed some of your code-formatting problems. Study that before your next post.

Answer (score 1):

A Dictionary does not have a length method.  A  Dictionary can give you a String that has a length method.

You call getWord on the Dictionary, which returns a String, which would have a length.  But you didn't retain the String, so you can't ask it for its length.

Maybe you meant

```
Dictionary dict = new Dictionary();
String randomword = dict.getWord(int_random);   
char[] letters = new char[randomword.length()];
```

Note that the length of a String is fetched by a method call, not as a direct read of a field.  That is, parentheses are required after the name.

This has better names, given that a 'Dictionary' is not actually a 'word'. Good naming is half the battle when it comes to understanding program code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```java
class Dictionary {
    Random r = new Random();
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();

    Dictionary() {
        l.add("UNIVERSITY");
        l.add("COLLEGE");
        l.add("ACADEMY");
    }

    String randomWord() {
        return l.get(r.nextInt(l.size()));
    }

    void printInfo() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{ l = %s }".formatted(l);
    }
}
```

```java
Dictionary d = new Dictionary();
String s = d.randomWord();
int n = s.length();
```